# Node.js - Generate web service server/client skeleton from wsdl

Tags: node.js, soap, wsimport

I'm looking for a tool like wsimport for node.js, with which I can autogenerate service/client from wsdl.

Comment: Take a look at this article http://www.jowanza.com/post/125602755114/dealing-with-soap-apis-in-nodejs

Answer (score 1):

You can use soap package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/soap)

The client part has a method describe. You can use the return of this method to easy generate (via templating) your skeletons for client and server

see https://github.com/benerone/soapStub

Comment: Could you explain more of how to use this? I expected xml-results but I get empty javascript with a bunch of useless comments in the functions.

Comment: I added a section called "use workflow" section which explain how to use it. see https://github.com/benerone/soapStub#use-workflow